# Drupal6 - product comparison

Tags: drupal-6

Hi
I have not using any shopping cart module, just created a content type (product) and defining several field(attribute) for each product feature.
I want to ask is there any module in Drupal for product comparison or field comparison?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but there is a way to do it with the Flag module and Views.  It will take more work than just turning on a module, but the outcome is the standard product comparison you're looking for.  See [this article](http://www.ireckon.com/web-dev/cms/drupal/ubercart-product-comparison/).

Answer (score 0):

**The article is no longer online: here the content of the original post.**

Ubercart Product Comparison

For me, using Ubercart in Drupal as an e-commerce solution for your website is the way to go. I have been using Ubercart for years now for a number of web design and development projects, and there are a massive amount of contribute modules to beef it up. One feature that I have been keen to work on is a Product Comparison feature, which would allow users to select products and have them display on a page, providing them with a nice and easy layout to easily compare their selected products.

After searching around the web, I found a few articles and posts from people looking for this feature, asking how it could work or if anyone had done it, but couldn’t find anything that said “here it is, this is how it can be done”. So, after a little bit or research and a bit of a play, I have come up with a solution which is not that difficult to achieve and only requires some already existing Drupal modules with just a few tweaks.

Note: This tutorial assumes that you already have a working ecommerce site with Ubercart installed. Best to also try this on a test environment and not a live website.

Step 1. Download Required Modules

Download, install and enable the following modules.

Views (I used 6.x-2.11, I haven’t tested it with any other releases)
Flag (I used 6.x-2.0-beta3, I haven’t tested it with any other releases)
Step 2. Flags configuration – Setting up your “compare”

Once you have enabled the Flags module, go to the flags administration page at /admin/build/flags.

Click the Add link, enter the name of your flag (something like “compare”), and leave the flag type as “node”, and submit.

On the next screen you will need to configure your new flag. Complete the following fields (changing the values if you like). I setup my configuration so only registered users of the website could compare products.

Title – Compare Products
Flag link text – Add to compare
Flagged message - [title] has been added to your compare
Unflag link text – Remove from compare
Unflagged message – [title] has been removed from your compare
Flaggable content – Product
Check “Display login link for anonymous users.” and for anonymous link text add “[login] to add to your compare”
For flag access, check flag and unflag for authenticated users
Under Display options select “Display link on node page” and “JavaScript toggle” as link type

Click submit to save your flag.

With the settings we used, the “flag link text” should now display on your product nodes. Clicking it should make the “flagged message” appear and the link changed to your “unflag link text” using JavaScript.

So what we are doing here is just flagging nodes – it’s actually pretty simple. We are flagging/unflagging them as “compare product”, so you should now be able to (by clicking on the link provided on your products) add and remove products to compare on your website.

Now we have done this, we need to create a page to display our “flagged” products, in which this case is the products we want to compare.

Step 3.  Creating out Compare Products Page

Go to the Views Administration page, enabling the Flag module creates a default flag view.  You can use this as a reference, or even change this view to what you need, it’s totally up to you. All we need is a view with (at least) the settings explained below.

DEFAULTS

Basic Settings – Use at least the following settings
Title: Product Comparison
Style: Table
Items per page: Unlimited
Access: Authenticated user
Empty text: Full HTML
- You have not yet added any products to compare. Click the “Add to compare” link when viewing a product to add it to this page.

Relationships
Add the following relationship:
Flags: Node flag
- label: compare
- check “Include only flagged content”
- flag: select the flag you created in step 2
- by: current user

Fields – You can put whatever fields here you would like to show up against each product. You must include the Node Title, and ideally you would want to show a thumbnail of the product, its price and description and the unflag link to allow users to remove it from this page. I have the following fields for my compare:
Content Image using an imagecache, linking to product
Node: Title linking to product
Flags: Flag link
- Relationship: select the one you added
Product: Sell Price
Node: Teaser

Filters
Node: Published Yes

AND SAVE

Now add a new page display view and give it a URL, then save. Navigate to your new compare page using the URL you entered. If you haven’t “flagged” any products yet, go do so and once done you should see those products displayed on your Compare Products page!!!

But, there is one slight issue. Because we needed to use Style: Table to get the layout to better suit a compare list, it still doesn’t display it the way we need it too.  We want to display each of the products horizontally, with each field label shown on the far left so it is easy to compare our products. To do this we need to retheme the table style for our view.

Step 4. Theme the table output of the view

Under Theme: Information for our view, it displays a list of all the possible templates for the display plugin and for the style plugins. Look for the list titled Style output. This is what we want. It lists the possible templates we can use to change the theming of the style output. The first one it displays is the generic template for the table style output but we don’t want to use this one, because if we do we could effect any other table style view that may be on the site. So best to use the next one across, mine was called views-view-table–flag-compare.tpl.php.

Create a new php file and name the file to the template name you want to use. In my case my file is named views-view-table–flag-compare.tpl.php.

Paste the Drupal 6 code from here http://drupal.org/node/174578 into your template file.

Then place the file in your themes directory – and presto! Your comparison table should be laid out more like a comparison style grid. Below is a screenshot of what my Comparison page looks like after a little bit of extra styling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module: https://drupal.org/project/comparison

Allows the comparison of the attributes of two or more nodes by generating a table. A checkbox is added to nodes to allow them to be included in the comparison. If two or more nodes are selected a link is added to a page with a comparison table.